# What does "across" in "get across the river" mean?

Tags: meaning

[Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/across) gives this definition about across

> from one side to the other of something with clear limits, such as an area of land, a road, or a river

and this example

> They're building a new bridge across the river

Apparently, a bridge is one of the possible ways to **across** the river.

Simply in this specific context, a bridge is a kind of **across**.

Besides that, is there other ways could be counted as **across**?

How about by swimming or by a raft?

How about jumping directly from one side to the other side by a motorcycle, by a car, or by a human cannonball?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than enumerating all the ways to cross a river, I will point out usage errors in your question.
"Across" is not a verb or a noun, it is a preposition, so you can't say "ways to across the river", or "a kind of across".
Your original example is good - "a bridge across the river", and you can say "I want to go across the river".
In those examples, "across the river" is a prepositional phrase showing where the bridge is, and where you want to go.

Comment: Thank you so much. You are a great contributor. All kinds of bridges in my OP could be described as "bridge **across/over** the river", right?

Comment: The examples in your pictures are not bridges. They are means of crossing the river, or ways to get across the river, but they are not bridges.